# SSRS : image from custom code

Tags: reporting-services

I am using custom code in my RDL to generate a PNG containing barcode font encoded data.

the code itself works... if I throw it into a console app, and save the byte array it returns to a file, Windows/MSPaint/etc are able to open it no problem.

But within the RDL, I'm having trouble showing it as an image.

My custom code:

```
Public Function BarCode_39(ByVal text as String) As Object
    ... generate System.Drawing.BitMap
    bitmap.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png)
    memstream.Flush()
    return memstream.ToArray()
End Function
```

tried setting the function to return Byte()... nothing seems to work

thoughts? ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

found out from https://blog.oraylis.de/2012/04/ssrs-custom-drawing-code/ that I had to change it from being an embedded image, to being sourced in the Database.

I also switched the code signature to returning Byte() for clarity